# CV Gap: PhD dropout with no reliable reference

Tags: cv

I spent 2 years doing a PhD. Not only did the study fail, my paths parted with my main and only supervisor in the worst possible manner. I don't know how to account for the gap on my CV due to the following reasons:

1.) It was 100% research, I cannot say I completed certain subjects or credits to swing it into a positive light.

2.) I obviously don't have a good (or any) reference to account for the 2 years in the PhD.

3.) I can't lie and say I worked as a research assistant during that time to account for the gap. I tried it, and I failed. The recruitment agency through which I tried to work nailed me on the fact that I could not provide them with the contact details of a supervisory figure for the time I spent working as a "research assistant". It's totally impossible to get away with not having a reference for your most recent "job".

I don't know what to do with my CV.

Any help would be substantially beneficial at this stage!

Comment: What country are you in? (also this seems like a question for workplace.SE rather than academia.SE)

Comment: How come there is no record of you being enrolled in this PhD program?

Comment: @solanacea: There certainly is a record at the university of my enrollment for the PhD. It reads: "PhD. Module: Thesis. Credits 700. Status incomplete". It repeats for every year I was enrolled. Other than the phd thesis "module" there are no other "modules" to complete in the programme.

Comment: In which case, this not really a gap in your CV. You were a graduate student for those two years. Your CV should say so. People fail to complete degrees for various reasons all the time. A gap is when you are unemployed, travelling the world, a stay-at-home parent, in prison, etc. where there is nothing on the CV for the 2 years between say 20XX and 20XX+2. Sure, you might be asked why you did not complete the degree in an interview and you should answer that question honestly. However, it does not need to be explained on a CV.

Answer (score 6):

You need to fill that gap. Employers have to allow for the worst case. Currently, they have no evidence that distinguishes your PhD attempt from two years sitting around doing nothing, or even two years in prison.

First contact your former supervisor. Even if they cannot give you a good reference for your research skills etc., they may be willing to say you were a PhD student and roughly what you were doing during those two years.

If that does not work, try the department and the school. You are not looking for a recommendation as a researcher, just a statement that you were registered as a graduate student during that period.

In dealing with potential employers, you can say that you tried being a PhD student but it did not work out, and is not the right path for you.

Comment: I agree and you certainly make a good point. It's comforting to know then, that I am not looking for a recommendation as a researcher, but a validaion of the fact that I was there doing a phd. I thought the reference HAS to be a supervisory figure that was in my direct line if reporting. If you put it this way, I will contact another senior researcher that was appointed in the same department who followed the progress closely, even though I did not report to him directly. Thank you.

Comment: Might I also ask - what is your opinion about removing the said PhD from the qualifications section, and placing it in the job experience section under the heading "postgraduate researcher"?

Comment: Your direct supervisor would be best - that is why I suggested contacting them first.

Answer (score 2):

Try being honest. "I was a PhD student but it ended badly." More people than you might think would understand a bad academic relationship. I have also seen references given from other people in the lab (postdocs, senior grad students).

Comment: once again thank you for your advice. As I said in a comment to another person who commented above, I never thought of putting up a person for a reference that is willing to testify that I was a phd student. I thought that it has to be a person in a supervisory role whom I reported to directly in the line of work. thank you.

Comment: Might I also ask - what is your opinion about removing the said PhD from the qualifications section, and placing it in the job experience section under the heading "postgraduate researcher"?

Comment: @Helpless I have upvoted this answer mainly for the first sentence. I would have a section labeled "Education" that includes your successfully completed degree(s) and also notes that you spent 2 years as a PhD student without receiving a degree. The practical problem with trying to call it something else is that a prospective employer is likely to find out the truth in following up on references, and will discount everything else you say in your CV. Why do you want to hide the fact that you were accepted into a PhD program?

Comment: @patricia: Thank you for feedback. I am faced with using standard templates from recruitment agencies. Theire layout starts with qualifications, by date. This is an immediate eyesore, as an incomplete phd will be at the top of the list. If I move the phd to the later section entitled work experience under the heading postgraduate researcher, I am given a chance to list the responsibilities I undertook during the time period. Although postgraduate researcher is definitely the alternative term for phd researcher, I do see your point of view on the complications involved!

Comment: The main thing is to make sure that if someone both reads your CV and finds out your complete background, they will not feel they have been deceived. You do seem to be forgetting that admission to a PhD program is a significant achievement in itself.

Comment: @patricia: truer words have not been spoken. Well said!